# Glass not Transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency, glass

I'm a novice in Blender and my problem is the roof isn't transparent everywhere, when I put camera in a certain angle the location of the transparent changes.

I use BlenderGuru pro lighting skies for the light.

[image: glass]

Comment: Possibly inverted normals - try Recalculate Normals.

Comment: when asking questions about materials please include an image of the nodes you are using.

Comment: It could be a reflection.

Answer (score 0):

What Rich said, also might be worth a shot doing ctrl a - set rotation and scale, as not doing so can cause some bizarre behavior in both editing and object mode.